# Swift - Invoke Custom Delegate Method

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I am using [BMPlayer](https://github.com/BrikerMan/BMPlayer) library and want to implement custom control, for which I have the following class which confirm to following protocol

```
@objc public protocol BMPlayerControlViewDelegate: class {
    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, didChooseDefition index: Int)
    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, didPressButton button: UIButton)
    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, slider: UISlider, onSliderEvent event: UIControlEvents)
    @objc optional func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, didChangeVideoPlaybackRate rate: Float)
}

open class BMPlayerControlView: UIView {
    open weak var delegate: BMPlayerControlViewDelegate?
    open weak var player: BMPlayer?

    // Removed rest of the code for clarity

    open func onButtonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
        autoFadeOutControlViewWithAnimation()
        if let type = ButtonType(rawValue: button.tag) {
            switch type {
            case .play, .replay:
                if playerLastState == .playedToTheEnd {
                    hidePlayToTheEndView()
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        delegate?.controlView(controlView: self, didPressButton: button)
    }
}
```

I am extending BMPlayerControlView class to extend the control view using the following code.

```
class BMPlayerCustomControlStyle3: BMPlayerControlView {

}

class BMPlayerStyle3: BMPlayer {

    class override func storyBoardCustomControl() -> BMPlayerControlView? {
        return BMPlayerCustomControlStyle3()
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I invoke `didPressButton` delegate method? I don't want to overwrite `onButtonPressed`, I tried the following

```
extension BMPlayerCustomControlStyle3:BMPlayerControlViewDelegate {

    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, didChooseDefition index: Int) {
        
    }

    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, didPressButton button: UIButton) {
        print("Did Press Button Invoked")
    }

    func controlView(controlView: BMPlayerControlView, slider: UISlider, onSliderEvent event: UIControlEvents) {
        
    }
}
```

And this doesn't seem to work, what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: try putting `super.controlView(controlView: controlView, didPressButton button)` in your overridden method. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `BMPlayerControlView` subclass to *also* act as the delegate object, you need to set the `delegate` property as well (and conform to the `BMPlayerControlViewDelegate` protocol as you are already doing).

One way to do so is by *overriding* the `delegate` superclass property in your subclass:

```
class BMPlayerCustomControlStyle3: BMPlayerControlView {

    override open weak var delegate: BMPlayerControlViewDelegate? {
        get { return self }
        set { /* fatalError("Delegate for internal use only!") */ }
    }
}
```

Of course, when using the delegate internally such as this, you *won't* allow it to be used by `BMPlayerControlView` clients at all. The overridden `set` above ensures you get an error if trying to do so.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar You *still* need to keep that `extension BMPlayerCustomControlStyle3 :BMPlayerControlViewDelegate..` around as well ;)

Comment: You are right Paulo, I did miss that, and when I added it gives me another error which says `Fatal error: Delegate for internal use only!`

Comment: I commented and got another error, `Cannot override mutable property with ready only property delegate`

Comment: See my updated answer... you probably commented out the entire setter ;)